# Setting Up & using Let's Encrypt SSL certificates with IIS Web Sites/Apps running on MS Windows Server 2019 instance in Amazon Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, amazon-lightsail, certbot-dns-plugin

I have an [Amazon Lightsail MS Windows (2019) Server](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/host-net-web-app/) instance with static IP and a registered verified domain name, let's call it `my-iis-website-test.net`, running an IIS web site, having a static HTML page at root default web app URL http://my-iis-website-test.net and a sample .NET Web API running at http://my-iis-website-test.net//test1/WeatherForecast (see screenshots at P.S.).

Now, I wanted my IIS web apps/API to be secured with `Let's Encrypt SSL certificates`.
I tried to toss-out tons of articles both in Amazon AWS knowledge base and on Internet but I didn't find any useful straightforward tutorial how to implement my solution using [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org).

For MS Windows Server LightSail instance, the solution, I have found, seems to be to use AWS Load Balancer ([SSL/TLS certificates in Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/understanding-tls-ssl-certificates-in-lightsail-https) - see link in the bottom of the referred web page).

But I don't currently need an AWS Load Balancer, I wanted to use a simpler solution with `Certbot`, similar to the ones presented in the following tutorials for the Amazon Lightsail `Linux` instances:

- [Tutorial: Using Let’s Encrypt SSL certificates with your WordPress instance in Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-wordpress)
- [Tutorial: Using Let’s Encrypt SSL certificates with your LAMP instance in Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-lets-encrypt-certificates-with-lamp)

They don't need an AWS Load Balancer, do they?

IOW, I'm missing a proven straightforward

- Tutorial: Using Let's Encrypt SSL Certificates with your IIS Web Sites running on MS Windows Server 2019 Instance in Amazon Lightsail

If there is no one, which can be `googled`, then I wanted to make this 'tutorial' prepared and tested here with the help of the StackOverflow members. I have collected some information - `Certbot` seems to be available for MS Windows (Server):

- [Web Hosting Product on Windows](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=webproduct&os=windows)

and [Route53 DNS Authenticator plugin for Certbot](https://pypi.org/project/certbot-dns-route53/) is described in very brief online docs [Welcome to certbot-dns-route53’s documentation!](https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). The only question (left) is how to apply all this information to make my IIS Web Site running on MS Windows Server (2019) instance running on Amazon Lightsail?

NB: I must note my Amazon Lightsail MS Windows 2019 Server instance is currently running as a `free-tier` one - first three months promotion. If using a `free-tier` instance would be a `stopper` to enable SSL/TLS on this instance then it wouldn't be a problem to upgrade it to a paid instance.

P.S. Screenshots:

A. Default IIS Web site serving static index.html at http://my-iis-website-test.net

[image]

B. Test .NET Web API/APP within default IIS Web Site http://my-iis-website-test.net//test1/WeatherForecast:

[image]